# Kubernetes Jenkins connectivity Issue

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, azure-aks

I set up the kubernetes on EC2 instances over ubuntu platform, everything working fine. But now I have deployed a Jenkins pod, after that, I am able to access the Jenkins in the browser. Now my question is how can I connect Jenkins with my machine.

My Jenkins pod IP:- `10.43.0.8`

My Kubernetes Master private IP:- `192.168.105.229`

I am able to ping with each other. But how I can access my master machine using Jenkins, so I can create the pods through Jenkins.

[image: IMG1]]
[image: IMG2]]

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this. A couple that I can think of:

- Use the [Jenkins Kubernetes Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin). If you install this on your Jenkins master (which is also running on a pod) and also if you configure it to talk to the same Kubernetes cluster (meaning the kube-apiserver) then you can create/remove pods using the plugin. More on how to configure [authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/) and [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) in Kubernetes
- Manually configure Jenkins slaves running as 'user'. Then on the 'user's some directory create a `~/.kube/config` that has the configuration to talk to your Kubernetes cluster. From there you can just issue `kubectl` commands to create/remove pods. You would still need to configure authentication/RBAC.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how I use master machine as a slave by Jenkins. I can't use kubernetes plugin, because I have setup the Kubernetes on normal Ubuntu machines. And deployed the Jenkins by pod Right! So now I want to access the master machine through Jenkins execute shell.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a pod running in Kubernetes you need to expose it as a service and possibly an ingress resource 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/